# Why would this be list index out of range?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am doing a bit of NLP and have about 4000 sentences to parse and I am doing it by this means:

```
ipython-input-> in create_arrayed_tokens(array)
     12     for i in range(len(array)):
     13         array.pop(0)
---> 14         concat_string = ' '.join([array[i]])
     15         tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(concat_string)
     16         words = [word.lower() for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
```

In this code snipped I am getting list index out of range for line 14, even though it is limited to the length of the array already? It does not matter even if I take away some constant values so it is not caused by the pop I don't think.
Thanks,

Comment: I would guess it's because you are `pop`ing as you go through the loop.

Comment: @Haveaniceday that was it I can't believe I didn't notice it in the for loop thank you'

Comment: Np :). I've done it myself before too.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in comments by user Have a nice day